# Why Is This Wordpress Query Returning 18 Results Instead of Three

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want to find users whose usernames start with "developer"; however, when I used the query below, I got 18 results when only two should return, based on the number of users in the database. Is there something wrong with the query that is causing this?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_users.ID,wp_users.user_login
FROM wp_users
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta
    ON ( wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id )
WHERE wp_users.ID !='1' AND wp_users.user_login LIKE 'developer%' OR (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'nickname' AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE 'developer%') OR (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name' AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE 'developer%')
ORDER BY user_login ASC
```

The actual results:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [user_login] => developer [id] => 6 )
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [user_login] => developer [id] => 6 ) 
    [2] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [user_login] => developer [id] => 6 ) 
    [3] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [user_login] => developer [id] => 6 ) 
    [4] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [user_login] => developer [id] => 6 ) 
    [5] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [user_login] => developer [id] => 6 ) 
    [6] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [user_login] => developer [id] => 6 ) 
    [7] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [user_login] => developer [id] => 6 ) 
    [8] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [user_login] => developer [id] => 6 ) 
    [9] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [user_login] => developer [id] => 6 ) 
    [10] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [user_login] => developer [id] => 6 )
    [11] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [user_login] => developer [id] => 6 )
    [12] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [user_login] => developer [id] => 6 )
    [13] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [user_login] => developer [id] => 6 )
    [14] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [user_login] => developer [id] => 6 )
    [15] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [user_login] => developer [id] => 6 )
    [16] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [user_login] => developer [id] => 6 )
    [17] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [user_login] => developer [id] => 6 )
    [18] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [user_login] => developer [id] => 6 )
)
```

Comment: Users are duplicated here due to multiple records in usermeta, you can make use of `DISTINCT` keyword, e.g., `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT wp_users.ID.....`

Comment: Your query is returning 19 rows for 1 user (user_id: 6) because there are 19 rows in `wp_usermeta` for this user. You are not using any data from `wp_usermeta` so why are you joining to it at all? If you change your SELECT list to `SELECT wp_users.ID,wp_users.user_login, wp_usermeta.*` you will be able to see the 19 rows. I would advise against continued use of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` as it [has now been deprecated](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=12615).

Comment: @nnichols Thanks for replying. They are joined because I want to find users whose user_login, nickname, or first name matches "developer," as the user could use the same name for any of these. However, I want only one record returned, not each record found. I have updated the post to reflect my intent. Also, SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS was added by Wordpress. I simply added onto the $query->query_where property. I don't want to change anything that would break Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do all users have wp_usermeta entries for `nickname` and `first_name`? If not, you may need to change the join to a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT wp_users.ID, wp_users.user_login
FROM wp_users
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta
    ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id
    AND wp_usermeta.meta_key IN ('nickname', 'first_name')
WHERE wp_users.ID != 1
AND ( wp_users.user_login LIKE 'developer%' OR wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE 'developer%')
ORDER BY user_login ASC
```

Comment: This is perfect for which I am looking. I am not an expert on WordPress, but it seems as if wp_usermeta has certain default entries, including nickname and first_name, for all users. I came to this conclusion after deleting the met_value entry for my first name and the meta_key entry, first_name, is still present.